# Homebrew - pyexif2 - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: macos, homebrew, pyexiv2

I installed homebrew and brew doctor complained that my path /user/local/bin wasn't above /usr/bin, so I corrected this and then tried to install exiv2 and pyexiv2 using the following command:

```
brew install exiv2 pyexiv2
```

I then get the following error:

```
bubbles-MacBook-Pro:Desktop bubble$ brew install exiv2 pyexiv2
Warning: exiv2-0.23 already installed
==> Downloading http://launchpad.net/pyexiv2/0.3.x/0.3.2/+download/pyexiv2-0.3.2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/pyexiv2-0.3.2.tar.bz2
==> Patching
patching file src/SConscript
==> scons BOOSTLIB=boost_python-mt
      boost::python::detail::converter_target_type<boost::python::to_python_value<std::string&> >::get_pytype() in exiv2wrapper_python.os
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
scons: *** [build/libexiv2python.dylib] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Any ideas? I really need pyexiv2 to work on this macbook.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/10/homebrew-and-pyexiv2/) helpful.

I just used brew to install the dependancies.

```
brew install scons boost exiv2
```

Then installed pyexiv2 from source with some tomfoolery. I [downloaded the latest tarball](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/download.html), exported it and `cd`'ed into it from terminal.

```
cd pyexiv2-0.3.2
echo "env['FRAMEWORKS'] += ['Python']" >> src/SConscript
scons BOOSTLIB=boost_python-mt
sudo scons BOOSTLIB=boost_python-mt install
```